# Reclassify slope raster

Tags: qgis, slope, reclassify, cost-path

I want to reclassify a slope raster as part of Least Cost Path Analysis, but I'm a little bit confused about the reclass rules.

My rules look like this at the moment (numbers left are degree):

0 thru 3.434 = 1

3.435 thru 5.143 = 5

5.144 thru 89 = 20

I'd like to have everything under 3.434 classfied as quite easy to pass through, 3.435 to 5.143 should be harder but still possible and everything over 5.144 basically impossible (or at least very hard to pass). Do the reclassified values represent these thoughts or should I change them?
I also thought about adding more rules to make it more detailed, what do you think?

Comment: The costs are relative to one another, so I wouldn't be terribly fussed about the absolute cost value you've assigned, provided you feel that the relationship between the costs is representative. For instance, the second slope class is roughtly 5x as hard to traverse than the first slope class.

Number of classes really depends. What phenomena are you describing? How do you plan to visualize the results? Will you transform the data somehow? Does the result feed into another analysis?